# Why does my child with space does not work in firebase?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

My database is this ->

```
 {
  "140107": {
    "Guest First Name": "As",
    "Guest Last Name": "Rodrigues",
    "Email": "aaa@yahoo.com.br",
    "Country": "Brazil",
    "Check-In date": "11-Jun-2016",
    "Check-Out date": "12-Jun-2016",
    "Room": "Cama Casal com suite",
    "Unit No": 1,
    "Subtotal": 90,
    "Revenue": 90,
    "Currency": "BRL",
    "Create Date": "19-May-2016"
  }
}
```

My code is this

```
public  void ProcuraReservaporemail(){
    String email = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
    myRef = database.getReference("reserva/");
    myRef.orderByChild("Email").equalTo(email).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           // Reserva reserva1;
            for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               // reserva1 = new Reserva(childSnapshot);

                String Unit = (String) childSnapshot.child("Unit No").getValue();
                textview2.setText(Unit);
                textview2.setText( childSnapshot.child("Unit No").getValue(String.class));
}
}
```

The instruction `childSnapshot.child("Unit No").getValue(String.class)` generates an error because my bank with this space.I would have to change that so that this error does not happen anymore? I thought about changing all my bank more and more work.Do not have a specific error for the Activity stopped working.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Please give us the error; we aren't magicians with psychic powers

Comment: Do not have a specific error for the Activity stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
(String) childSnapshot.child("Unit No").getValue()
```

or

```
String.valueOf(childSnapshot.child("Unit No").getValue())
```

Comment: Can you explain how this makes a difference?

Comment: And maybe you should've waited until the OP clarified his error; we can't know what's wrong without it.

Comment: I put String Unit = (String) childSnapshot.child("Unit No").getValue();
                    textview2.setText(Unit); function and even then the activity has stopped working.

Comment: But the "String.valueOf (childSnapshot.child (" Unit On "). GetValue ())" worked.